# Use phantomjs callbacks with python and selenium driver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

I'm looking for a way to use phantomjs callbacks with python and selenium driver but i'm unable to make it work, i'm trying with a simple example like update the title of stackoverflow.com site once the site is loaded, using onLoadFinished callback from phantomjs documentation

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html

but it could be any other event callback, and here the code i'm using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

user_agent = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en)) " +
    "AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3"
)

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = user_agent
dcap["phantomjs.page.onLoadStarted"] = "function() {document.title = 'test';};"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)

driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")
url =  driver.current_url
print "title: " + driver.title
```

any ideas if this is possible or if i'm doing something wrong?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

PhantomJS recently dropped Python support altogether. However, PhantomJS now embeds Ghost Driver.

A new project has since stepped up to fill the void: Ghost.py (http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/).